# Canvas drawing for my web application

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I just started using Canvas for my web game project and faced a problem.

I'm using this code to render the game:

```
function render(f){
if(charoffset.x == null) charoffset.x = charpos.x*tilescale;
if(charoffset.y == null) charoffset.y = charpos.y*tilescale;

if(!tiles) tiles = [];
if(f){
    log("Welcome.","gold");
    
}
var canPassthrough = function (){
    if ((def.passable(this.type))&&(typeof this.type !== 'undefined')){
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
};
if(!f) lighting.update();
canvas.getContext("2d").clearRect(0,0,sq,sq);
for (var i = 0; i < map[charlvl].length; i++){
    if(!tiles[i]) tiles[i] = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < map[charlvl][i].length; j++){
        if(!tiles[i][j]) tiles[i][j] = placetile(i,j);
        drawtile(tiles[i][j]);
        placeitem(i,j);
    }
}
ui.overlay.text("casting shadows...");
//shadowcaster(20);
    var tex = document.createElement("img");
    tex.src = "../img/charplaceholder.png";
    var hero = canvas.getContext("2d");
    hero.globalAlpha = 1.0;
    if(charoffset.x>=map_scroll.x&&charoffset.y*tilescale>=map_scroll.y){
        var pos = {
            x: charoffset.x - map_scroll.x - tilescale,
            y: charoffset.y - map_scroll.y - tilescale
        };
        hero.drawImage(tex,pos.x,pos.y,tilescale,tilescale);
    }
function placetile(x,y){
    var obj = {};
    obj.type = map[charlvl][x][y].id;
    obj.canPassthrough = canPassthrough;
    obj.state = {explored: false, lit: false};
    obj.coords = {x:x,y:y};
    obj.offset = {x:x*tilescale,y:y*tilescale};
    return obj;
}
function drawtile(t){
    if(t.offset.x>=map_scroll.x&&t.offset.y>=map_scroll.y){
        var pos = {
            x: t.offset.x - map_scroll.x - tilescale,
            y: t.offset.y - map_scroll.y - tilescale
        };
        if(!t.state.explored&&!t.state.lit){
            return false;
        }
        else if(t.state.lit&&t.state.explored){
            
            var tex = document.createElement("img");
            var tile = canvas.getContext("2d");
            tex.src = def.css.tile(t.type);
            tile.globalAlpha = 1.0;
            tile.drawImage(tex,pos.x,pos.y,tilescale,tilescale);
            return true;
        }
        else if(t.state.explored&&!t.state.lit){
            var tex = document.createElement("img");
            var tile = canvas.getContext("2d");
            tex.src = def.css.tile(t.type);
            tile.globalAlpha = 0.25;
            tile.drawImage(tex,pos.x,pos.y,tilescale,tilescale);
            return true;
        }
    }
}
function placeitem(x,y){
    return;
    if (loot[charlvl][x][y]){
        for(var i=0;i<loot[charlvl][x][y].length;i++){
            var tile = document.createElement("div");
            var tileid = loot[charlvl][x][y][i].type;
            tile.className = def.css.item(tileid);
            tile.coords = {x:x,y:y};
            document.getElementById("x" + x + "y" + y).appendChild(tile);
        }
    }
}

if(f){
    camera.center(charpos.x,charpos.y);
    ui.overlay.text("loading the dungeon...");
    ui.overlay.hide();
}
}
```

Function `render()` is fired by various events, such as character moving, map dragging, lighting update, etc.

This is the result:
[image]

I would like to add inset shadows to walls so it's more clearly visible those are walls. I tried experimenting with canvas context shadows, and used this:
[image]
It's supposed to draw a transparent rectangle and a shadow for it at 100, 100 with size 20, 20, however this applies shadow to every drawn tile instead.

I feel like I'm using drawing wrong. Can anyone explain how to effectively
use canvas to achieve desired effect?

Comment: canvas behaves like a state machine, whenever you change a state of e.g. shadowBlur it will apply to all succeeding calls to fill / stroke / ....

Comment: @le_m but I can change alpha of some tiles to indicate explored and lit

Answer (score 3):

Do not use the 2D API shadow options , they are very very slow ( and that is an understatement of how bad they are). You are much better off creating the shadows as part of the tile set and rendering them with either `ctx.globalAlpha` set to less than 1 and/or use one of the many composite modes. Eg `ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "multiply";` Or `overlay`, `color-burn`, `hard-light`, and `soft-light`. You can even use a combination to get a very good shadow effect.

Creating the shadows as part of the tile set will give a much more realistic effect as the shadow API is just for shadows cast from flat object floating above a flat surface, not for 3D objects protruding from the screen that may have sloped sides in the z direction.

If you do not wish to create the shadows as part of the tile set consider creating the shadow tile set at onload using an off screen canvas via the shadow API options. Then render from that to the canvas using alpha and composite options